# Keeping revision history using VentureCraft/revisionable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, revisionable

I have to display history of changes that are made in my app (like update, insert->who did it , what field changed and when). I am using laravel 4 and I also downloaded [this](https://github.com/venturecraft/revisionable). But the problem is that I am not clear of how to use it. Where to put the folder VentureCraft ? and how to get username or id of the person who did the action. Is there any other way to keep track of history in laravel?

EDIT:

Car model

```
namespace MyApp\Models;

class Car extends Eloquent {
    use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;
}
```

View

```
@foreach($description->revisionHistory as $history )
    <li>{{ $history->userResponsible()->username }} changed {{ $history->fieldName() }} from {{ $history->oldValue() }} to {{ $history->newValue() }}</li>
@endforeach
```

and it shows :
Undefined variable: description

Am i missing something in controller?

Comment: I should think there are install instructions that go with that repository?

Comment: Where is `$description` coming from? Is that a field on the `Car` model?  Instead, try just `$car->revisionHistory as $history`

Comment: @watcher Description is a field in Car model. I also tried $car->revisionHistory as $history and it shows undefined variable $car. where should i declare it?

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant route you're trying to hit from your routes.php and the controller method? I don't think you're actually loading a `$car` instance but there's not quite enough information here yet.

Comment: @ watcher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672101/trait-venturecraft-revisionable-revisionabletrait-not-found

Comment: i made a new question pls take a look, I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Check out the README, it looks fairly self explanatory. Install with composer, migrate, then use the `RevisionableTrait` in your models that you wish to keep the update history of.  You can should then be able to get the history of an object with:

```
 $object->revisionHistory;
```

They even have a simple example of usage within a blade template:

```
@foreach($account->revisionHistory as $history )
    <li>{{ $history->userResponsible()->first_name }} changed {{ $history->fieldName() }} from {{ $history->oldValue() }} to {{ $history->newValue() }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes but it showed errors. I  think I was doing something wrong because instructions aren't very clear. Pls could you edit your answer step by step what should I do. I mean in wich folder should i put VentureCraft  and then about loading I wasn't clear

Comment: how about you update the question with what you already tried?  I think it would be a lot easier to understand whats going wrong for you in this instance.  I would vote to reopen if you provide us with a better picture of the steps you've already taken to try and install this package.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: I'm not exactly sure for instance what 'VentureCraft' folder you're talking about. Do you have composer installed? If so, just add `"venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*",` to your composer.json file and issue `composer update` command (or `php composer.phar update`) from the project root and that is all that is required in order to install the src files for the package.