# Trait 'Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait' not found

Tags: php, laravel, revisionable

I am using laravel 4 and I want to keep track of history of all transactions made to a table. I followed those steps

1. added `"venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*"` at composer.json
2. `php composer.phar update`
3. run in the root of my project this :

   php artisan migrate --package=venturecraft/revisionable

and it says "nothing to migrate"

then i copied the migration file from the package in my app/database folder, and changed the classname from CreateRevisionsTable to something like CreateRevisionTable and the table was created in my database. Then I added this in my Car model:

1.

```
 class Car extends Eloquent {
    use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;

    protected $keepRevisionOf = array(
    'Description'
    );

}
```

Then in my controller:

```
 $description = Car::find($id);
        $history = $description->revisionHistory;
```

And then in my view:

```
 @foreach($history->revisionHistory as $h )
                <li>{{ $h->userResponsible()->username }} changed {{ $h->fieldName() }} from {{ $h->oldValue() }} to {{ $h->newValue() }}</li>
                @endforeach
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "ajessup/gae-laravel": "dev-master",
                "venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*"
    },
```

And the result is:

```
Trait 'Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait' not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Go to the source of the library you added. See if that trait in actually there.  If it is not, try my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the item in composer to:

`"venturecraft/revisionable": "~1.8"`

This will match any version from 1.8 to but not including 2.0.

EDIT: This solution makes no difference.

EDIT: Maybe.

Comment: ok i am missing something, should I copy and paste the package venturecraft in my project root or just include "venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*" and run composer update? Because in the folder that I downloaded it has 4 files "FieldFormatter", "RevisionableTrait", "Revisionable", "Revision" BUT THIS FILES AREN'T IN MY PROJECT EVEN AFTER composer update and dump-autoload

Comment: tried "venturecraft/revisionable": "~1.8" and the same

Comment: I was wrong. I ran `composer require venturecraft/revisionable 1.*` in an empty directory and it gave me `1.8` which had the trait.  However, when I created a class with that trait, there were no errors.

Comment: explain me something pls. After download the packages. should I include them in my project? or just add "venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*" in composer.json of my project and then at the root of my project run : composer.phar update? I am not copying and paste the package that downloaded and there are not in my project

Comment: With composer you don't need to download the packages to add them manually.  When you use composer, the vendor/autoload.php file needs to be included, then all classes in the vendors are exposed.  I am assuming Laravel does this for you.

Comment: well now it is updated with theing v command you gave me composer require venturecraft/revisionable 1.* But it is saying Undefined variable: history. What am i doing wrong now?

Comment: Well it looks like your problem is solved, odds are even though you added the library to your project, the classes weren't loaded.  This new error is unrelated, simple a bug you should be able to solve.

Comment: well thank you :) if you could help me with the steps how to call  $car = Car::find($id);
        $history = $car->revisionHistory; in my controller or model ??

Comment: it shows this in view Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$revisionHistory

Comment: I'm afraid I am not familiar with Laravel.  You may want to re-tag your question as `php traits composer`, then ask another question related to MVC with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Just run composer dumpautoload and it should work...